# how to debug an exception with return value nil in ruby class/module error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create an wrapper class , rclient to make a http call using Excon. in my controller class, I instantiate and call a method on that class. while debugging, I noticed in the post method of the client class @client variable is always nil.

I change the code (see approach 2 ) , instantiate a @cient variable with new instance of Excon and use that variable in the same method , then it is not null. I'm not sure why in approach first, i can access @client variable that is set in the initialize method. any ideas?

approach 1

```
module API
   class rclient

      def initialize
        @client ||= Excon.new('http://example.com')
      end

      def post
         #error @client is nil 
         post_response = @client.Post(path:'/create', body:{date:'somedata'}); 
      end
   end
end


class my controller < ApplicationController

    def create
       req = API::rclient.new()
       req.post
    end
end
```

approach 2

```
module API
   class rclient
      def post
         @client = Excon.new('http://example.com')
         post_response = @client.Post(path:'/create', body:{date:'somedata'}); 
      end
   end
end


class my controller < ApplicationController

    def create
       req = API::rclient.new()
       req.post
    end
end
```

Comment: `class rclient; end` returns `SyntaxError: (eval):2: class/module name must be CONSTANT`, so this clearly is not your real code. There's no telling what other minor issues you may have introduced when copying this into your post. Please post your actual code, how you are invoking it, and what your stack trace is.

Comment: thank you for your comments. here is the actual code as asked                                              ``` module API    class RestClient                                                                                def initialize    @client ||= Excon.new('http://example.com') end                                  def post  post_response = @client.post(...) end

Comment: @anothermh - thanks. here is the actual code   . calling the post method in this class after instanciating , results @client variable as nil. where as if I perform both operations in the same function , code works. so why does the post method does not recognize the variable when it is in the initialize method?    ```                                    module API   class RestClient                                                                                      def initialize   @req ||= Excon.new(...) end   def post  res = @req.post(...) end       end end ```

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. Update your question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@client` variable going to be initialized for both variants. Probably smth is missing in this code "adaptation" for the described scenario. Here is slightly adjusted demo code that you can check:

```rb
# app.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)

module API
  class Rclient

    def initialize
      @client ||= Excon.new('http://example.com')
    end

    def post
      post_response = @client.post(path:'/create', body: URI.encode_www_form(date: 'somedata'))
    end
  end

  class Rclient2
    def post
      @client = Excon.new('http://example.com')
      post_response = @client.post(path:'/create', body: URI.encode_www_form(date: 'somedata'))
    end
  end
end

req1 = API::Rclient.new
req2 = API::Rclient2.new

req1.post
req2.post

raise 'First implementation failed' unless req1.instance_variable_get(:@client).is_a?(Excon::Connection)
raise 'Second implementation failed' unless req2.instance_variable_get(:@client).is_a?(Excon::Connection)
```

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'excon'
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. i think this has more to do with the access to that client variable that i create in the initialize method and which i'm trying to access in a different function.

Comment: you can easily access the instance variable within different methods of the same instance of the class as shown with API::Rclient. Can you provide some test code that you're hesitating on top of the updated snippet?

Comment: that's the code, I have been trying to call from a controller.

Comment: that's the code, I have been trying to call from a controller.                                                 when I had initialize and Post function and called the code as below, I didn't get any response.                                                                                                        newRestClient = API::Rclient.new      response =  newRestClient.Post                            but when I had only one function to initialize , post a request , I did get a response.

Comment: from the sample within current answer you receive post response https://prnt.sc/rif15k